# How do I erase App name from my Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I did `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` but something similar is still appearing in my app with the App name on it. Before just doing NoActiobar in themes used to remove it. Apparently it's the tool bar. 
What's the difference? And how do I remove my app name from it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Action Bar and newly introduced Toolbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665018/what-is-the-difference-between-action-bar-and-newly-introduced-toolbar)

Answer (score 1):

Main advantage of using Toolbar over ActionBar

1. It can be customised easily
2. It can be placed any where in the screen
3. You can have more that 1 toolbar in a screen.

For implementation detail refer [App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) and [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = new Toolbar(getSomeContext()); // or link to Standing Toolbar.
mToolbar.setTitle(""); // Empty String...
```

Have fun!