# What are the different bars (status bar, action bar, navigation bar, tool bar etc.) available in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

What are the different bars available in android and where are they located? Pics to support each type would be highly appreciated and helpful for beginners.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The status bar is where the clock, battery icon, notification icons, and the like reside. Most of the time, it is at the top of the screen. This is provided by the system; the app does not directly manipulate the contents of this bar.

The action bar (sometimes referred to as the app bar), if it exists for an activity, will be at the top of the activity's content area, typically directly underneath the status bar. Activities control whether there is an action bar and, if so, what it looks and works like.

The navigation or system bar is where the HOME, BACK, etc. buttons are. This is usually on the opposite side of the screen from the status bar, and therefore usually is at the bottom of the screen.  This is provided by the system; the app does not directly manipulate the contents of this bar.

[image: Bars on an Android 4.x device]

Comment: Thanks. May I know what is a tool bar,  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" and 
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"

Comment: @user3705478 `Toolbar` is advance version of `ActionBar` with more feature.

Comment: @Ironman May I know how advanced? What are those extra features?

Comment: @user3705478 visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665018/what-is-the-difference-between-action-bar-and-newly-introduced-toolbar we can easily control `Toolbar`.

Comment: It's "Navigation bar" not System Bar

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub: I wrote "The navigation or system bar is where the HOME, BACK, etc. buttons are.". In the early days of when this bar existed (2011), it was called the system bar. Nowadays, where the bar exists, it tends to be called the navigation bar.

Comment: And where is the notification bar?  Some of our UI people use this term even though I can't find it in the Material Design docs.

Comment: @ScottBiggs: I would assume that's the status bar.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid confusion and call them:

- status bar
- app bar (action bar is also ok)
- navigation bar

[image: android ui screen layout]

**Synonyms**

**action bar**, **app bar**, and **title bar** all refer to the same thing. A  [**`Toolbar`**](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar) is a certain implementation of this bar.

One of the purposes of the **status bar** is to show notifications. Therefor some call it the **notification bar**.

The **navigation bar** is sometimes called the *system bar*, but the latter name should be avoided. It's too easy to mistakenly think that the *system bar* contains system information like battery level and network connection, while that's actually the job of the **status bar** to show these things. The term **navigation bar** is much clearer. I've also [seen it getting called `home bar`](https://support.iadea.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004165666-Hide-home-bar-and-show-full-screen-on-Android).

Note that iOS also has a navigation bar where it serves a slightly different purpose compared to android - the purpose overlaps with android's navigation and action bars. Moreover, the navigation bar in iOS is typically (always?) located at the top, just below the status bar. See [Navigation Bars on developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/navigation-bars/).

**References**

- [Android bars at material.io](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-bars.html) (status bar, app bar, navigation bar)
- [Add the app bar at developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar) (app bar, action bar, Toolbar)
- [`@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts?hl=de#notitle-theme) is a theme without an app bar. It was later called action bar in the code, e.g. in `@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar`. (title bar, action bar)
- [Navigation Bars in iOS on developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/navigation-bars/) (different purpose of navigation bar in iOS)