# Android API 19: Action Bar not displaying menu_main.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.gatech.seclass.glm">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name="edu.gatech.seclass.glm.Activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:icon="@android:color/background_light"
        android:id="@+id/select_list"
        android:title="Select List"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ///...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.select_list:
                return(true);

        }
        return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }

    //...
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edu.gatech.seclass.glm.Activity.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="440dp"
        android:id="@+id/groceryListContainer"
        android:layout_weight="0.66" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/add_list"
        android:layout_width="374dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:id="@+id/addList"
        android:onClick="addList"
        android:layout_weight="0.26" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything I read leaves me to believe that this should work, but I get an action bar that only displays the App Name. I have confirmed that onCreateOptionMenu is actually hit as well. Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you are adding Action Bar? Some info about Action Bar: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Comment: I thought I was with `onCreateOptionsMenu`. Where would that be done?

Comment: "but I get an action bar that only displays the App Name" - should the question be that the Action Bar is not displaying your menu?

Comment: @MarkKeen yes. Updated edit

Comment: Try and remove the call the the super class, remove this line -> `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`

Comment: Tried that. Same issue

Comment: What device are you using? I know at least the old galaxy devices hid the overflow menu unless you hit the physical menu key

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using a Samsung Galaxy J3 6

Comment: Have you tried on an Emulator?

Comment: You set a color as the menu item icon. Try something you can differentiate from background.

Comment: @EugenPechanec That was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in onCreateOptionsMenu before return.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
```

Comment: The used theme already sets the title, and displays. The problem is the menu not inflating/showing.

Comment: On create method of this activity, Pls do this.         getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Some Title");

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually setting action bar () in onCreate method:
On Android 5.0 (API 21) it is ToolBar:

```
    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setActionBar(tb);
```

Please look at samples:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html

And here diff between ToolBar and ActionBar:

[What is the difference between Action Bar and newly introduced Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665018/what-is-the-difference-between-action-bar-and-newly-introduced-toolbar)

Comment: There's no toolbar in the activity XML, though

Comment: This is api level 19